# How to get Lookup ID from Search API with REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest, search-results, lookup-column

I'm trying to get the **ID** of a lookup field when using search api.
My query looks something like this:

```
/_api/Search/query?querytext='ListId:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012'&selectproperties='Title,Company'
```

Where **Company** is the lookup field, in a specific list.

The result looks like this:

```
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
  <d:Key>Company</d:Key>
  <d:Value>Some company</d:Value>
  <d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

I have created a managed property which looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. However, you could add the `ID` as a "column to show" in the List:

[image]

after which you will have a corresponding crawled property:

[image]

which you then can map to a managed property

[image]

After this you can use that managed property to retrieve the id of the linked company:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
  },
  "Key": "companyid",
  "Value": "2",
  "ValueType": "Edm.String"
}
```

The column (`Company:ID`) could be removed from all Views and - using PowerShell even from the DisplayView.

Comment: Brilliant! It even works with multi lookup. Interesting note; I tested with several fields, the crawled properties was named after fields Title (not InternalName), one was called _"SharePoint:ID"_. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days before you get the bounty, but so far I'd be surprised to find a better solution :)